# Understanding Truth Values of Basic Logical Statements.

Tags: logic

I'm starting a course in proofs and our first two chapters have been on set theory and logic, both of which I have understood to an extent. However, one of my homework questions asks me the following and I'm not quite sure what I'm being asked to do.

Suppose the statement $((P\land Q)\lor R)\Rightarrow(R\lor S)$ is false. Find the truth values of said variables.

In English, I believe the above claims that to say that "if either P and Q or R, then either R or S" is false. Am I being asked to find which combinations of P, Q, R, and S satisfy the above statement, or something else entirely?

I apologize in advance for resorting to asking a homework question on MSE but it's the only one I haven't finished and I'd like to know how to approach a question like this if it were to be on a quiz tomorrow.

Comment: Your translation in English is correct.  Now, is it possible for $R$ to be true and the implication be false?

Comment: You need to assign truth values to $P,Q,R,S$ such that the statement $((P\land Q)\lor R)\Rightarrow(R\lor S)$ is false. In fact there is only one possible assignment.

Comment: Oh okay, so the implication's falsity holds if R is false, and the rest is gravy?

Comment: Yes, $R$ must be false, but, as @EclipseSun suggests, there is only one choice for each variable.  What happens now if $P$ is false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry, I struggled with this myself and Math SE has offered me good solutions, so I'll give the same help to you.

$((P \wedge Q) \vee R) \Longrightarrow (R \vee S)$ is false when $((P \wedge Q) \vee R)$ is true and $(R \vee S)$ is false. And $((P \wedge Q) \vee R)$ is true when P and Q are true and when R is either true or false. So if the whole statement is false, then $(R \vee S)$ is false, and so $R$ must be false and $S$ is false as well.

and you get

```
   T                  F
```

$((P \wedge Q) \vee R) \Longrightarrow (R \vee S)$

The whole statement is false

Because:

\begin{array}{C|C}
p & q & p \Longrightarrow q \\
\hline
T & T & T\\
T & F & F\\
F & T & T\\
F & F & T
\end{array}

Comment: Note that you can use `\land` and `\lor` to get "$\land$" and "$\lor$" in LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for the edit, yep I noticed that, but I don't know why for me \vee and \wedge stick more lol

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing proofs:

$((P \land Q) \lor R) \to (R \lor S) \equiv$

$(R \lor S) \lor \lnot ((P \land Q) \lor R) \equiv$

$(R \lor S) \lor (\lnot (P \land Q) \land \lnot R) \equiv$

$(R \lor S) \lor ((\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land \lnot R) \equiv$

$(R \lor S \lor \lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (R \lor S \lor \lnot R) \equiv$

$(R \lor S \lor \lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \equiv$

$\lnot (\lnot R \land \lnot S \land P \land Q)$

Is false precisely when $\lnot R$, $\lnot S$, $P$ and $Q$.  I find that there is frequently an easily-interpretable form for most logic statements somewhere along the way to converting to either CNF or DNF.